# Android SQLite Database error inserting column

Tags: android, sqlite

I made an android database with three columns but when I try to save it gives me this error.

This is my logcat.

```
02-07 06:02:04.762      877-877/tubapps.datepickerdb E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table incomes has no column named date
02-07 06:02:04.832      877-877/tubapps.datepickerdb E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting amount=123 date=4/2/2015 payer=McDonald's
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table incomes has no column named date (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO incomes(amount,date,payer) VALUES (?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
            at tubapps.datepickerdb.DBHelper.insertIncome(DBHelper.java:59)
            at tubapps.datepickerdb.IncomeActivity.run(IncomeActivity.java:188)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
    public static final String INCOME_TABLE_NAME = "incomes";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_PAYER = "payer";
    public static final String INCOME_COLUMN_DATE = "date";


    private HashMap hp;

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table incomes " +
                        "(id integer primary key, amount text, payer text, date text)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS incomes");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertIncome  (String amount, String payer, String date)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("amount", amount);
        contentValues.put("payer", payer);
        contentValues.put("date", date);

        db.insert("incomes", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }
    public Cursor getData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from incomes where id="+id+"", null );
        return res;
    }
    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, INCOME_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }
    public boolean updateIncome (Integer id, String amount, String payer, String date)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("amount", amount);
        contentValues.put("payer", payer);
        contentValues.put("date", date);
        db.update("incomes", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteIncome (Integer id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("incomes",
                "id = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }
    public ArrayList getAllIncomes()
    {
        ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from incomes", null );
        res.moveToFirst();
        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(INCOME_COLUMN_PAYER)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

}
```

And this is my activity.

```
public class IncomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int from_Where_I_Am_Coming = 0;
    private DBHelper mydb;
    TextView payer;
    TextView amount;
    TextView date;
    int id_To_Update = 0;

    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private TextView dateView;
    private int year, month, day;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_income);

        payer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_payer);
        amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_amount);
        date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_date);

        dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_date);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        showDate(year, month+1, day);



        mydb = new DBHelper(this);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
                Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
                id_To_Update = Value;
                rs.moveToFirst();
                String amo = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.INCOME_COLUMN_AMOUNT));
                String pyr = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.INCOME_COLUMN_PAYER));
                String dat = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.INCOME_COLUMN_DATE));
                if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
                save.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cnc);
                cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                amount.setText((CharSequence) amo);
                amount.setFocusable(false);
                amount.setClickable(false);

                payer.setText((CharSequence) pyr);
                payer.setFocusable(false);
                payer.setClickable(false);

                date.setText((CharSequence) dat);
                date.setFocusable(false);
                date.setClickable(false);

            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_income, menu);
            } else {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Edit_Income:
                Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
                save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cnc);
                cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                amount.setEnabled(true);
                amount.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                amount.setClickable(true);

                payer.setEnabled(true);
                payer.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                payer.setClickable(true);

                date.setEnabled(true);
                date.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                date.setClickable(true);

                return true;
            case R.id.Delete_Income:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteIncome)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                mydb.deleteIncome(id_To_Update);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog d = builder.create();
                d.setTitle("Are you sure");
                d.show();

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void run(View view) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                if (mydb.updateIncome(id_To_Update, amount.getText().toString(), payer.getText().toString(), date.getText().toString())) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                if (mydb.insertIncome(amount.getText().toString(), payer.getText().toString(), date.getText().toString())) {
                } else {
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setDate(View view) {
        showDialog(999);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (id == 999) {
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // arg1 = year
            // arg2 = month
            // arg3 = day
            showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
        }
    };

    private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
                .append(month).append("/").append(year));
    }

}
```

Does anybody know why I get this error cause I don't understand why. I have inserted that column.

Comment: Firstly check if your column name is right? If it is then uninstall your app and clean your project and run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `date` column is added later in `incomes` table query.

so try to pass different version :

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 2);
```

Comment: @GeorgeZoiade: welcome George. I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

try foloowing:
1) diffrent name for date column like "date_added"
2) asign value in single quote like '07/02/2015'

or folow this link:
http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-insert-datetime-value-in-sqlite-database/